# how to order kif testcase sequences?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, kif-framework

I used the latest version of KIF framework and create several testing cases (subclass of KIFTestCase).

May I know is there any way to change the order of the sequences of testing runs?

for examples I have testA.m testB.m testC.m ... 
how to make the sequence such as testB.m testC.m testA.m when I hit a cmd+U for testing?

Answer (score 3):

It's ordered alphabetically, example:

```
    - (void)testB {} will be the second test

    - (void)testA {} will be the first test

    - (void)testC {} will be the third test
```

Comment: yes, I know it is ordered alphabetically, just wondering is there any method so we can put the testing sequences as we want and run it, instead of using KIF's default alphabetical order

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in KIF currently, as far as I know.

Technically it is alphanumeric rather than alphabetical ordering, which points to a useful work-around. A work-around is to use alphabetical prefixes to test names that group them logically, by incrementing a count to the A, B, C. This eliminates most of the disadvantages of the alphabetical system as you can separate out groups of tests that need to be together, and can re-order those tests or add additional tests in each of those series without having to rename every test in your KIF test class.

```
- (void)testA1_RelatedTest1
- (void)testA2_RelatedTest1
- (void)testA3_RelatedTest3

- (void)testB1_OtherAreaOfTesting1
- (void)testB2_OtherAreaOfTesting2

- (void)testC1_FinalTestCategory1
- (void)testC2_FinalTestCategory2
- (void)testC3_FinalTestCategory3
```