# Xcode8 / Swift 3 in XCTest does not run in Alphabetical order anymore

Tags: swift3, xcode8, xctest

XCTest does not have an ability to sort methods in a sequential order so I used an old hack in the naming convention of the methods to enforce test order execution:

```
testHomePage
testLogin
```

to

```
test01Login
test02Hompage
```

That used to work in **Xcode 7 Swift 2.2**

In **Xcode 8 / Swift 3** this seems to not work anymore! So **Xcode 8 / Swift 3** theres no alphabetical, sequential or any sorting logic?

My team and I looked into possibly modifying the **pbx / xml** file, but theres nothing to edit there either. Anyone have a suggestion of how to enforce test to run in a specific order?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want tests to run in a particular order? I would say that it is a bad idea if your tests depend on each other.

Comment: Do you implement the setUp method? This should usually be all you need to prevent the need for a specific sequence

Comment: @ganzogo In the example I have above I'm demonstrating a blackbox UI automated way of executing a sanity test. I can't go to the HomePage without going into the Login view first. 

Maybe the way I wrote the example above is not clear. I am trying to say if I have those 2 methods listed above in 1 class and I want those methods to execute in a certain order how do I do that?

Comment: @GerdCastan I do have the setUp() method in the base class and again in the test class as an override func setUp()  to perform some additional actions in-between test methods that are unique to that test. Is there a way to specify order in the setUp method?

Comment: Also just to add this convo. I understand that sequential ordering defeats the purpose of unit testing. However, this Unit testing methodology doesn't applying to UI testing.

Answer (score 0):

I would refactor to avoid the need to enforce an ordering. Even though these are UI tests, rather than unit tests, the same principle applies in my opinion: each new test should start with a fresh system.

So, for example, refactor out the logic to log in (without any testing) and use that in all tests that require a logged in user. You will also want a method that will "reset" the system in some sense - so in your case, log the user out perhaps. In my experience this is better called from a `setup` method than a `teardown` method, because if a test stops unexpectedly for whatever reason, your next test run will always fail.

The downside to this approach is that your tests are going to take longer to run because your app will be repeatedly logging in and out, but this fact should encourage you to focus purely on UI and to keep more fiddly logic detail (username string length, password validity, etc..) in your unit tests.

Comment: I can appreciate the refactored code for testing purposes only. We have discussed this approach in great length. Our conclusion is that were testing a hacked version of the code and therefore results are inaccurate. The entire effort of end-to-end testing is just that, end-to-end. We want to be able to produce real world conditions. This discussion can go even further by taking the mock server approach and injecting fake data. This effort is to create a sanity test that is very high level and test the basic functions of the app before a merge request can be posted.

Comment: A light weight, sequential, structured test that is in the pre-commit phase in the CI pipeline. UI implies so many variables and is very difficult to always have separated tests without dependancies. In the testing world of Unit that is best practice and in the world UI functional testing it is not. A user either has to gather data and inject or login before another result can be produced. Apple has mentioned that you can order test targets alphabetically which is not ideal.

Comment: Why would anyone want to create 50 testing targets and then sort them? Additionally, speed is of the essence. If a test takes 60 seconds in a structure form and then you switch to a practice that exponentially raises test times to 360 seconds, then that is not considered acceptable in any large scale environment. In fact, if we had known this was going to happen we would of chosen a different framework, which we are on the cusp of doing, possibly KIF. I appreciate the input @ganzogo

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess every project is different and you will choose what makes the most sense to you. Certainly I have successfully used KIF on past projects. Have you considered having 2 separate UI test targets? Smoke test (or end-to-end test) could run on CI and then a more in depth target which would run before releases perhaps or only after large merges.

Comment: It looks like were going to have to use more testing targets : ( Thank you for your help @ganzogo

Comment: I found this to be interesting, Alphanumeric instead of Alphabetical 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24950678/how-to-order-kif-testcase-sequences

Comment: HOLY CRAP AND I NEVER USE CAPS, THAT WORKED! It doesn't run alphabetically or numerically it runs alphanumerically! Like hexadecimal 'A1, A2, A3'. Why couldn't Apple put that in a doc some where? Why did it cost my company 5 resources and several days to guess the new change? Why does it take the guys who are using KIF to figure this out? Ugh. I hope this saves somebody from pulling their hair out. Thanks for looking into with me @ganzogo

Comment: Glad you got it sorted - you should add that as a separate answer and accept it. I still think it's preferable to not rely on the order of the tests, but that's not really what you asked in the first place :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution we found to help with UI test execution order.

1. Use gitlab
2. Create several test targets in yml
3. Where tests need to run in a certain order encapsulate them in the gitlab.yml

Here is an example of a test that runs on its own and another that requires sequential ordering:

```
test_search:
stage: test
tags:
 - ios
script:
 - xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace company.xcworkspace -scheme yourcompany -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=latest' -only-testing:Test/testSearch

test_profile_and_edit:
stage: test
tags:
 - ios
script:
 - xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace company.xcworkspace -scheme your company -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=latest' -only-testing:Test/testProfile
 - xcodebuild test-without-building -workspace company.xcworkspace -scheme your company -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=latest' -only-testing:Test/testProfileEdit
```

If you have a scenario where login is require include an override method in setup to check if user is logged in.